# Multilevel JSON diff in python

Tags: python, json, compare, diff, unordered

Please link me to answer if this has already been answered,
my problem is i want to get diff of multilevel json which is unordered.

```
x=json.loads('''[{"y":2,"x":1},{"x":3,"y":4}]''')
y=json.loads('''[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":4}]''')
z=json.loads('''[{"x":3,"y":4},{"x":1,"y":2}]''')

import json_tools as jt
import json_delta as jd


print jt.diff(y,z)
print jd.diff(y,z)
print y==z
print x==y
```

output is

```
[{'prev': 2, 'value': 4, 'replace': u'/0/y'}, {'prev': 1, 'value': 3, 'replace': u'/0/x'}, {'prev': 4, 'value': 2, 'replace': u'/1/y'}, {'prev': 3, 'value': 1, 'replace': u'/1/x'}]
[[[2], {u'y': 2, u'x': 1}], [[0]]]
False
True
```

my question is how can i get y and z to be equal or if there are actual differences depending on non-order of the JSON.

kind of unordered List of dictionaries but i am looking for something which is level-proof that is list/dict of dictionaries of list/dictionaries ...

Answer (score -5, accepted):

solved it partially with following function

```
def diff(prev,lat):
    p=prev
    l=lat


    prevDiff = []
    latDiff = []

    for d1 in p[:]:
        flag = False
        for d2 in l:
            if len(set(d1.items()) ^ set(d2.items())) == 0:
                p.remove(d1)
                l.remove(d2)
                flag = True
                break
        if not flag:
            prevDiff.append(d1)
            p.remove(d1)

    prevDiff = prevDiff + p
    latDiff = latDiff + l

    resJSONdata=[]
    if len(prevDiff) != 0:
        resJSONdata.append({'prevCount':len(prevDiff)})
        resJSONdata.append({'prev':prevDiff})
    if len(latDiff) != 0:
        resJSONdata.append({'latestCount':len(latDiff)})
        resJSONdata.append({'latest':latDiff})

#     return json.dumps(resJSONdata,indent = 4,sort_keys=True)
    return resJSONdata
```

it's not doing it recursively into level into levels but for my purpose this solved the issue

Answer (score 21):

Check out this python library [jsondiff](https://pypi.org/project/jsondiff/) , that will help you to identify the diff's

```
import json

import jsondiff

json1 = json.loads(
    '{"isDynamic": false, "name": "", "value": "SID:<sid>", "description": "instance","argsOrder": 1,"isMultiSelect": false}')

json2 = json.loads(
    '{ "name": "", "value": "SID:<sid>","isDynamic": false, "description": "instance","argsOrder": 1,"isMultiSelect": false}')

res = jsondiff.diff(json1, json2)
if res:
    print("Diff found")
else:
    print("Same")
```

Answer (score 5):

UPDATED: See https://eggachecat.github.io/jycm-json-diff-viewer/ for a live demo! Now it has a JS-native implementation.

Affiliation: I am the author of this lib.

Yes! You can diff it with [jycm](https://github.com/eggachecat/jycm) which has a [rendering tool](https://github.com/eggachecat/react-jycm-viewer) out of the box.

It uses LCS, Edit distance and Kuhn–Munkres to diff arrays.

Here's an universal example with set in set and value changes in some set

```py
from jycm.helper import make_ignore_order_func
from jycm.jycm import YouchamaJsonDiffer

left = {
    "set_in_set": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "label:1",
            "set": [
                1,
                5,
                3
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "label:2",
            "set": [
                4,
                5,
                6
            ]
        }
    ]
}

right = {
    "set_in_set": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "label:2",
            "set": [
                6,
                5,
                4
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "label:1111",
            "set": [
                3,
                2,
                1
            ]
        }
    ]
}

ycm = YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, ignore_order_func=make_ignore_order_func([
    "^set_in_set$",
    "^set_in_set->\\[\\d+\\]->set$"
]))

ycm.diff()

expected = {
    'list:add': [
        {'left': '__NON_EXIST__', 'right': 2, 'left_path': '', 'right_path': 'set_in_set->[1]->set->[1]'}
    ],
    'list:remove': [
        {'left': 5, 'right': '__NON_EXIST__', 'left_path': 'set_in_set->[0]->set->[1]', 'right_path': ''}
    ],
    'value_changes': [
        {'left': 'label:1', 'right': 'label:1111', 'left_path': 'set_in_set->[0]->label',
         'right_path': 'set_in_set->[1]->label', 'old': 'label:1', 'new': 'label:1111'}
    ]
}

assert ycm.to_dict(no_pairs=True) == expected
```

you can set **no_pairs=False** to get the all pairs. Here's a rendered example:

[image]

As for the example here, you can use it as:

```py
from jycm.helper import make_ignore_order_func
from jycm.jycm import YouchamaJsonDiffer

left = {
    "data": [{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 4}]
}

right = {
    "data": [{"x": 3, "y": 4}, {"x": 1, "y": 2}]
}

ycm = YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, ignore_order_func=make_ignore_order_func([
    "^data",
]))

ycm.diff()

assert ycm.to_dict(no_pairs=True) == {}
```

Bonus, you the values are interrupted as coordinates on plain, you can even define a operator to
determine whether two points should be matched!(Then comparing their values)

Here's the code:

```py
from typing import Tuple

from jycm.helper import make_ignore_order_func
from jycm.jycm import YouchamaJsonDiffer
from jycm.operator import BaseOperator
import math

left = {
    "data": [
        {"x": 1, "y": 1},
        {"x": 10, "y": 10},
        {"x": 100, "y": 100}
    ]
}

right = {
    "data": [
        {"x": 150, "y": 150},
        {"x": 10, "y": 11},
        {"x": 2, "y": 3}
    ]
}


class L2DistanceOperator(BaseOperator):
    __operator_name__ = "operator:l2distance"
    __event__ = "operator:l2distance"

    def __init__(self, path_regex, distance_threshold):
        super().__init__(path_regex=path_regex)
        self.distance_threshold = distance_threshold

    def diff(self, level: 'TreeLevel', instance, drill: bool) -> Tuple[bool, float]:
        distance = math.sqrt(
            (level.left["x"] - level.right["x"]) ** 2 + (level.left["y"] - level.right["y"]) ** 2
        )
        info = {
            "distance": distance,
            "distance_threshold": self.distance_threshold,
            "pass": distance < self.distance_threshold
        }

        if not drill:
            instance.report(self.__event__, level, info)
            return False, 1 if info["pass"] else 0
        return True, 1 if info["pass"] else 0


ycm = YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, ignore_order_func=make_ignore_order_func([
    "^data$",
]), custom_operators=[
    L2DistanceOperator("^data->\\[.*\\]$", 10),
])

ycm.diff()

expected = {
    'just4vis:pairs': [
        {'left': 1, 'right': 2, 'left_path': 'data->[0]->x', 'right_path': 'data->[2]->x'},
        {'left': {'x': 1, 'y': 1}, 'right': {'x': 2, 'y': 3}, 'left_path': 'data->[0]',
         'right_path': 'data->[2]'},
        {'left': 1, 'right': 3, 'left_path': 'data->[0]->y', 'right_path': 'data->[2]->y'},
        {'left': {'x': 1, 'y': 1}, 'right': {'x': 2, 'y': 3}, 'left_path': 'data->[0]',
         'right_path': 'data->[2]'},
        {'left': {'x': 1, 'y': 1}, 'right': {'x': 2, 'y': 3}, 'left_path': 'data->[0]',
         'right_path': 'data->[2]'}
    ],
    'list:add': [
        {'left': '__NON_EXIST__', 'right': {'x': 150, 'y': 150}, 'left_path': '', 'right_path': 'data->[0]'}
    ],
    'list:remove': [
        {'left': {'x': 100, 'y': 100}, 'right': '__NON_EXIST__', 'left_path': 'data->[2]', 'right_path': ''}
    ],
    'operator:l2distance': [
        {'left': {'x': 1, 'y': 1}, 'right': {'x': 2, 'y': 3}, 'left_path': 'data->[0]',
         'right_path': 'data->[2]', 'distance': 2.23606797749979, 'distance_threshold': 10,
         'pass': True},
        {'left': {'x': 10, 'y': 10}, 'right': {'x': 10, 'y': 11}, 'left_path': 'data->[1]',
         'right_path': 'data->[1]', 'distance': 1.0, 'distance_threshold': 10,
         'pass': True}
    ],
    'value_changes': [
        {'left': 1, 'right': 2, 'left_path': 'data->[0]->x', 'right_path': 'data->[2]->x', 'old': 1, 'new': 2},
        {'left': 1, 'right': 3, 'left_path': 'data->[0]->y', 'right_path': 'data->[2]->y', 'old': 1, 'new': 3},
        {'left': 10, 'right': 11, 'left_path': 'data->[1]->y', 'right_path': 'data->[1]->y', 'old': 10, 'new': 11}
    ]
}
assert ycm.to_dict() == expected
```

As you can see jycm report addition and remove for points `{'x': 150, 'y': 150}` and `{'x': 100, 'y': 100}` for their
distances are too far (more than 10) and value-change for the other two points.

**P.S. RENDERER DEMO**

[image: gif-show]