# Compare 2 Json files and display the difference of second file

Tags: python, json

These are the two json files i have
JSON1.json

```
{

  "name": "HOSTNAME1",

  "chef_environment": "non_prod",

  "run_list": [

    "role[MyOrg-non_prod]",

    "role[rhel7-latest]",

    "role[middleware-nonprod-all]",

    "role[MyApp-middleware_corebase_prod]",

    "role[MyApp_envs-test]",

    "role[MyApp_envs-dev]",

    "role[MyApp_nfs_mount]",

    "role[MyApp_access-dev]",

    "role[MyOrg-client-wrapper]"

  ]

}
```

JSON2.json

```
{

  "name": "HOSTNAME2",

  "chef_environment": "non_prod",

  "run_list": [

    "role[MyOrg-non_prod]",

    "role[rhel7-latest]",

    "role[MyApp_unix_app-dev]",

    "role[MyApp_middleware_corebase_prod]"

  ]

}
```

These files may or may not be sorted. I need to get the unique values of JSON2 which are not available in JSON1

I have initially tried it using commands like

```
findstr /vig:JSON1.json JSON2.json  | grep -v name| grep -e MyApp -e MyOrg | tr -d '\n'| sed -e 's:"::g' -e 's: *::g'  -e 's:,$::'
```

However this dosent work, consider for example
In JSON1 i have an entry
"role[MyApp_middleware_corebase_prod]",

and in JSON2
"role[MyApp_middleware_corebase_prod]"

Note the difference in comma, although the entry is same and hence not unique, however due to presence of comma this is considered as unique and gives me an undesired output.

If i compare JSON1 vs JSON2 the expected output is 
**role[MyApp_unix_app-dev]**
as this is ONLY unique to JSON2

And if i compare JSON2 vs JSON1

**role[MyApp_envs-test],role[MyApp_envs-dev],role[MyApp_nfs_mount],role[MyApp_access-dev],role[MyOrg-client-wrapper]**

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45937169/10727144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set subtraction (difference) is what I think you actually want:

```
import json


with open('json1.json', 'r') as f:
    json1 = json.load(f) 

with open('json2.json', 'r') as f:
    json2 = json.load(f) 

json2['run_list'] = list(set(json2['run_list']) - set(json1['run_list']))

print(json.dumps(json2, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "HOSTNAME2",
  "chef_environment": "non_prod",
  "run_list": [
    "role[MyApp_unix_app-dev]"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. However Can we just print the contents of run_list i.e role[MyApp_unix_app-dev]

Comment: @baggi `print(json.dumps(json2['run_list'], indent=2))`

Comment: @baggi and you don't need to print it using `json.dumps(...)`, I just do that because it looks cleaner with the indent.

Answer (score 1):

you can use python set intersection

```
json1 = {

      "name": "HOSTNAME1",

      "chef_environment": "non_prod",

      "run_list": [

        "role[MyOrg-non_prod]",

        "role[rhel7-latest]",

        "role[middleware-nonprod-all]",

        "role[MyApp-middleware_corebase_prod]",

        "role[MyApp_envs-test]",

        "role[MyApp_envs-dev]",

        "role[MyApp_nfs_mount]",

        "role[MyApp_access-dev]",

        "role[MyOrg-client-wrapper]"

        ]

       }

json2={

          "name": "HOSTNAME2",

          "chef_environment": "non_prod",

          "run_list": [

            "role[MyOrg-non_prod]",

            "role[rhel7-latest]",

            "role[MyApp_unix_app-dev]",

            "role[MyApp_middleware_corebase_prod]"

          ]

        }
set1 = set(json1['run_list'])
set2 = set(json2['run_list'])
set3 = set1.intersection(set2)
```

Comment: Intersection just returns an empty set